# I made a Loop to verify is two enemies are colliding, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, game-physics

I made a loop in my game, that creates two rectangles at enemies and verify if they're colliding(or should verify) to return "true" to an if/else so it can prevent the enemies from continue walking... but it just doesn't work...

```
    public boolean isColiding(int xnext, int ynext) {
        Rectangle enemyCurrent = new Rectangle(xnext, ynext, World.TILE_SIZE, World.TILE_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.enemies.size(); i++) {
            Enemy e = Game.enemies.get(i);
            if (e == this)
                continue;
            Rectangle targetEnemy = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), World.TILE_SIZE, World.TILE_SIZE);
            if (enemyCurrent.intersects(targetEnemy)) {
                System.out.println("returned!!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

the "Game.enemies" is a list that contains all the enemies.
I made a function that renders the rectangles by itself and they're being rendered property, but it just doesn't work in the loop

Comment: In one place you are create a Rectangle with width/height = (16,16). In the other you are using World.TILE_SIZE. Can you confirm that this is/isn't an issue?

Comment: is not. the values are exactly the same, but the issue persists

Comment: If you added a method `getBounds()` to your Enemy class, you could just compare `current.getBounds().intersects ( enemy[i].getBounds );`

Comment: You should test to confirm that Rectangle.intersects works correctly for two rectangles that overlap (I know it does). Then you can to figure out why your rectangles are not overlapping when you think they are

Comment: You should try running it through the debugger

Comment: ok ok, ill try to do it, thanks for the help ^-^